# spring mvc -display values in dropdown list from DB

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a dropdown list like this

```
<form:select path="component" multiple="true" id="componentId">
    <form:option value="" label="--- Select Components---" />
    <form:options items="${componentList}" />
</form:select>
```

Here the componentLits prints the vaues stored in the db in the below format

```
 Boot Up(bootup),
              Channel Tuning(channelTuning)
              TOCOD(tocvod)
```

I have to display values in dropdown list `UI as  Boot Up , Channel Tuning, TOCOD`.dont need to display the values inside brackets.
              And while selecting the above values (for example if i choose `Boot UP` from dropdown its value will be `bootup` not the displaying one`(Boot UP))`
              how it is possible with `spring mvc form`

Comment: do you have a arraylist with this values? what is the problem? are the values not displayed?

Comment: values are displying in the dropdown in the Boot Up(bootup) Channel Tuning(channelTuning) format..i have to display  Boot Up, hannel Tuning only but while selecting Boot Up from dropdown list the value will be bootup..i mean the value inside the bracket..

Comment: i understand. the label should be Boot Up and the value "bootup". Is componentList a arrayList or a map or set or ... ?

Comment: Yes u r right !componetList is arrayList

Comment: ok, change it to a hashmap ..  Map< String, String > ttt = new HashMap<string, string="">();  
        ttt.put(" Boot Up", "bootup");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the arrayList to a hashMap.

```
Map< String, String > componentList= new HashMap<string, string>(); 
componentList.put(" Boot Up", "bootup");
```

After that the key will be displayed as value, and the value of the map as label.

```
<form:select path="component" multiple="true" id="componentId">
    <form:option value="" label="--- Select Components---" />
    <form:options items="${componentList}" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: how can i display tt in UI<form:select path="component" multiple="true" id="componentId">
    <form:option value="" label="--- Select Components---" />
    <form:options items="${tt}" />
</form:select>

Comment: could you please how it can be displying in the form select of dropdown list

Comment: one more doubt using java how can i split key values Boot Up(bootup)

Comment: Is the string  "Boot Up(bootup)"  like this stored in one column in the database? Use StringUtils from apache commons. The method is StringUtils.split("(") and please flag my answer as accepted.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/lang3/stringutils/org-apache-commons-lang3-stringutils-example/